# I cannot set default value to pass for a dictionary in method

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

What I am trying to do is to make a colors dictionary default, so in case of the user does not want to specify it we always have default colors for help.

I don't know how to tackle this problem.

```
class paint_window:
    def __init__(self, display_height,display_width, colors_dict ={black: (0,0,0),white : (255,255,255),red : (255,0,0)}):
        self.display_height = 800
        self.display_width = 600
        self.colors_dict = colors_dict
```

But I am getting this error :

```
File "/home/harsh/Documents/Python_pygame/paint_window.py", line 5, in paint_window
    def __init__(self, display_height,display_width, colors_dict = {black : (0,0,0),white : (255,255,255),red : (255,0,0)}):
NameError: name 'black' is not defined
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxpVW.png)

Comment: use `""` for dict keys

Comment: Use `black`, `white` and `red` in quotes, because they are supposed to be string literals unless you have defined them before.

Comment: Just replace with `colors_dict ={'black': (0,0,0),'white' : (255,255,255),'red' : (255,0,0)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, `black` is not defined. This is because `black` has nothing assigned to it. Instead of this:

```
{black: (0,0,0), white: (255,255,255), red: (255,0,0)}
```

You probably want this:

```
{'black': (0,0,0), 'white': (255,255,255), 'red': (255,0,0)}
```

Here, the dictionary keys are strings (keys can be any immutable object: strings, integers, tuples, and so on). Technically, you *could* also do:

```
black = 'black'
white = 'white'
red = 'red'
{black: (0,0,0), white: (255,255,255), red: (255,0,0)}
```

This works now because `black`, `white`, and `red` are valid names.

Comment: what do you mean by python dictionaries are string?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I meant that dictionary *keys* are strings.

Comment: Dictionary keys don't *have* to be strings (see my edits above), but it looked like in this case you wanted them to be.